# Cannot open output stream

Tags: java, android, stream, serversocket

For some reasons i have to set up on android SocketServer which waits for connection with computer. All is going good, socket with client (computer) is creating, but streams don't open. It's just pausing without any error or message.

client:

```
        s = new Socket(ip, 4567);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("ois..");// not showing, so can't open input stream
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("oos..");  // same here
```

server:

```
        socket = new ServerSocket(4567);
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection,,"); // showing
        client = socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected"); //showing
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("ois.."); // not showing
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("oos.."); // not showing too
        System.out.println("Stream,s opened");
```

My apk has INTERNET premissions. I'm using 4567 port. Any other application doesn't block the port.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening the ObjectOutputStream first in your server.

```
    socket = new ServerSocket(4567);
    System.out.println("Waiting for connection,,"); // showing
    client = socket.accept();
    System.out.println("Connected"); //showing
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("Stream,s opened");
```

Comment: I tried it before, but didn't help. Mixing it with setSoTimeout && keepAlive made it work. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any timeouts in there, which is why it just stops.

There's probably some network problem; have you verified the IP address of the device is correct?

It's unlikely, but there *could* be some firewall rule blocking the connection.